# How to write lock table while inserting data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb

## Objective

When user makes a request (REST API) I want to copy `N` records from table `source` to table `destination`.

## Current solution

1. Start the transaction.
2. Truncate table `destination`.
3. Insert into table `destination` select from `source` LIMIT `N` (Single query).
4. Commit the transaction.

## Problem

`N` can be between the range `100000` - `2500000`, if the user makes two request one after the other with `N` records then `2xN` records are being inserted.

Example flow:

1. [Action - 1] User makes a request to copy `100` records.
2. [Action - 1] Transaction starts.
3. [Action - 2] User makes a request to copy `200` records.
4. [Action - 1] Truncated table `destination`.
5. [Action - 2] Transaction starts.
6. [Action - 2] Truncated table `destination`.
7. [Action - 1] Insert query triggered.(Copy `100` records)
8. [Action - 2] Insert query triggered.(Copy `200` records)
9. [Action - 1] Transaction ends.
10. [Action - 2] Transaction ends.

Result: There are `300` records in `destination` table.

## Desired solution

I want to make sure that at any given point of time only one insertion happens.

1. Start transaction.
2. Lock `destination` table.
3. Truncate `destination` table.
4. Insert into `destination` table.
5. Unlock `destination` table.
6. End transaction.

Note that when I want to only write lock destination table only, **write** operations should not happen (but read operation should still happen).

## Other details

- MySQL (Database)
- NodeJS (REST API server)
- No stored procedures

## Temporary solution

Temporarily we are depending on a flag which we set in database before starting the transaction and then we unset it once the transaction completes. Any other request which arrives while the flag is set they will be terminated with a message (Process already running, please try again later)

Please help me out finding a better solution for this. Let me know if you need more details.

Thanks

Comment: MySQL can pend the request and execute it one by one when table locked. If you are afraid of timeout. Just set `connect_timeout` to enough long time you desired.

Comment: Maybe a better explanation on what you are trying to solve instead of how you want to solve it would render some better approaches, this one, fells terrible. Seems to me an [XYProblem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yeah I have mentioned my problem. I don't want 2 inserts to happen simultaneously.

Comment: @MatrixTai Can you please elaborate or point me to some references?

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-table-locking/, take a look, you could execute the requests one by one.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below queries as follow ...

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
LOCK TABLES `staff` WRITE;

-- inserts start here
INSERT INTO `staff` VALUES 
(2,'Jon','Snow',4,NULL,'Jon.snow@gameofthroneshbo.com',2,1,'Jon',NULL,'2006-02-15 03:57:16'),
(2,'Jon','Stephens',4,NULL,'Jon.Stephens@sakilastaff.com',2,1,'Jon',NULL,'2006-02-15 03:57:16');
-- till here

UNLOCK TABLES;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Hi @Saurabh Ande 
Note that, while a WRITE lock will lock new SELECT queries until it is converted to a READ lock or released via UNLOCK, it will not prevent SELECT queries already in the query cache from returning the cached results.

So I would be able to use select query on `staff` until I unlock it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you step back a ways and explain what the goal is?  Meanwhile, here is another implementation that might help:

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE dest;
populate `new` from `source;
RENAME TABLE dest TO old, new TO dest;
DROP TABLE old;
```

Notes:

- There is no lock or transaction other than each statement being atomic.
- Populating `dest` can take arbitrarily long without any locking issues.
- `dest` is always available except for a brief time during the `RENAME`, during which time activity on `dest` is blocked.

This is a generic way to atomically, and with minimal impact, reload a table.

Answer (score 0):

How about you optimize your SQL query to perform Lock-Unlock scenario while inserting records:

```
LOCK TABLES
    tbl_name [[AS] alias] lock_type
    [, tbl_name [[AS] alias] lock_type] ...

lock_type:
    READ [LOCAL]
  | [LOW_PRIORITY] WRITE

UNLOCK TABLES
```

More Info - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html